# Worth shortening all your long slugs?

Tags: links, seo

If you have a lot of posts with long slugs, for ex, **40-places-to-eat-snickers-bars-when-hungry**, is it worth converting them to something shorter?  For ex: **places-to-eat-snickers-bars**.  I've read a few articles that say it is, and other sources that say it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

No-one can say for sure what is the ideal URL-length. Mostly it is recommended to keep the URL below 60-70 characters. I recommend on reading [this](http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/internet/google-ranking-factors.htm), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702852/does-url-length-have-any-impact-on-seo) and [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329).